# How can I import a .xcframework file in a react-native wrapper library for iOS using podspec?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, gradle, podspec

We are building a react native wrapper library for Android and iOS which will import classes from native SDK(.aar and .xcframework) to implement native modules and native ui component.

Note:- SDK will be provided by the user who is using the library.

For now we have shared the library as package which can be installed in a react-native project direclty. On android we are able to import the sdk (.aar) through gradle.

Currently we have published the .xcframework to cocoapods and using as a dependency, in case if the sdk (i.e .xcframework) is updated we will have to publish the updated sdk to cocoapods. To solve this we are planning to import the sdk through posdpec.

How to import the .xcframework through podpsec or is there any alternative?

I tried to provide the relative path in vendored_frameworks of the podspec file, but no luck.

`s.vendored_frameworks = "{$rootdir}/../ios/Framework/mysdk.xcframework"`

If we are able to import the .xcframework through podspec it would be really helpful.

I would appreciate any resources, tutorials, or advice. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We have quite a similar case with our internal/published SDK.

Here's the source and vendored_frameworks of the .podspec file we use for consuming the published SDK:

```
s.source = { :http => 'https://<HOSTING_URL>/AwesomeSDK-3.14.1-internal.1.zip' }
s.vendored_frameworks = 'AwesomeSDK.xcframework'
```

For local usage / testing:

```
s.source = { :path => '.' }
s.vendored_frameworks = 'generated/Frameworks/AwesomeSDK.xcframework'
```

So, you can try messing up with the `.source` property, xcframework files work with .podspec.